Can "$\frac{dy}{dx}$" be defined uniquely under reasonable conditions for curves (relations) which aren't functions?
In solving differential equations, I have been taught that implicit solutions of the form $\{ (x,y) | R(x,y) = 0 \}$ are solutions only in the sense that any (single variable) differentiable function $f \subseteq \{ (x,y) | R(x,y) = 0 \}$ will be a solution to the differential equation.
However, in finding orthogonal trajectories of a family of curve  satisfying $y' = F(x,y)$, we look for curves in general (and not just functions) which satisfy the condition $$y' = \frac{-1}{F(x,y)}$$ at each point $(x,y)$ on the curve (for example, the orthogonal trajectories to the family of  lines through the origin are circles centered at the origin).
Here, it seems to be implicitly assumed that for each point $(x,y)$ on the relation (which will generally not be a function), there is one and exactly one way of defining $y'$, which I believe is equivalent to the fact that there is exactly one differentiable function $f \subset R$, with $R$ denoting the relation which solves the DE, passing through $(x,y)$.
Are there reasonable conditions under which this is true or do I need to determine explicitly if the relation that I've found satisfies this condition so as to be a valid orthogonal trajectory?

This will be the case provided $F(x,y)$ is at least $C^1$, by the implicit function theorem.  Of course, the relation should be written in a form that clears denominators, because $dx$ (like $dy$) can vanish; think of the case of the circle.

OP : Can "$\frac{dy}{dx}$" be defined uniquely under reasonable conditions for curves (relations) which aren't functions?
Yes , when we can make it "Parametric" in terms of $t$.
Let Curve $C(x,y)$ be like $x^2 + y^2 = 1$
Let $x(t) = \cos t$ , $y(t) = \sin t$ , which are indeed functions while $x^2(t) + y^2(t) = 1$.
Here , $x' = -\sin t$ , $y' = \cos t$ , which too are indeed functions.
Definition $dy/dx \equiv y'/x' = -1 / \tan t$ is hence suitable here.
We can extend this to most Curves.
More-over the orthogonal trajectories will make work out too.
UPDATE :
When is this way going to give unique values for the Derivatives ?
We must have at least the main criterion that the Curve must not have Self-Intersections.
In Circles & Curves with no Self-Intersections , each $(x,y)$ Point will have unique $dy/dx$ value.
When Self-Intersections occur , there could be multiple $dy/dx$ values at some $(x,y)$ Point.
Eg :

Here the Black Curve might have some "Parametrization" & we might get the $dy/dx$ values. Yet the Self-Intersections make it non-unique at certain Points , like shown by the Purple lines.
Additionally , we might have Singularities elsewhere , where even without Self-Intersections , $dy/dx$ either will not exist or might have multiple values. The Blue lines high-light that.
There could be more "Corner-Cases" to consider too.
I think , we should check each Solution to verify whether it is valid or not.

You used an explicit example here. Can you elaborate on why it is almodt always possible to parameterise?

I have updated that answer a little. Do tell me whether I am interpreting your question right.
